# Best Python 3.5 library for playing mp3 file on Raspberry pi 0 W

Tags: pi-zero, python-3

I've already tried VLC library but the cpu reach 100% usage frequently during file playing, I've also the necessity to track the state of the playing so to know when the file is ended etc., Any ideas?

Comment: By "reproduce", do you mean that you want to play the MP3? It might be a good idea to clarify that with an [edit] if you can.

Comment: Yes exactly what i mean, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might experience better performance using [`omxplayer`](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer):

> Omxplayer is a video player specifically made for the Raspberry Pi's GPU made by Edgar (gimli) Hucek from the XBMC/Kodi project. It relies on the OpenMAX hardware acceleration API, which is the Broadcom's VideoCore officially supported API for GPU video/audio processing.

If you're using Raspbian, `omxplayer` will already be installed. To output to HDMI, just run:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi <filename>
```

For further information, check the link above or use `man omxplayer` to read the manual page.

The Pi Zero uses a BCM2835 SoC, which supports Broadcom's proprietary media acceleration features. `omxplayer` can take advantage of this to gain better performance than software-accelerated playback.

To track whether playback has ended, you can use the [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.system) function in Python. Presumably, when playback is complete, the function will return 0 (exit code 0 implies success, generally, on Unix systems). The call is synchronous so your script will wait until playback is complete until moving to the next line.